# Props are not updating?

Tags: vue.js

Can anyone help me with this

I am using vuejs-paginate for pagination, and I wanted to show current selected page,
I want to update "currentPage" inside parent, in the child am not getting updated prop value

```
parent component
   <SPagination :count="count" :currentPage="currentPage" :itemsPerPage="itemsPerPage" @page-changed="setPage"></SPagination> 
         data () {
                return {
                  currentPage: 1,  // by default 1
                  itemsPerPage: 10
                }
              },
             methods: {
               setPage (pageNumber) {
                  let query = Object.assign({}, this.$route.query, { offset: (pageNumber - 1) * this.itemsPerPage, })
                  this.currentPage = pageNumber  // Page re-renders and this.currentPage lost  (I wanted to use 
                 this.currentPage into the child pagination component so that it could show the selected page)
                  this.$emit('setPage', query)
               }
             }

child component 

<paginate
    v-model="page"
    :page-count="totalPages"
    :page-range="3"
    :margin-pages="1"
    :click-handler="pageChanged"
    :prev-text="''"
    :next-text="''"
    :container-class="'pagination'"
    ref="paginate">
  </paginate>

data () {
    return {
      page: 1
    }
  },
 props: {
    count: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    currentPage: {
      required: true
    },
    itemsPerPage: Number
  },
 mounted () {
    this.page = parseInt(this.currentPage) // how Can I get selected page here 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`mounted` lifecycle gets called only when component is mounted. Instead you can use `computed` property, to ensure `this.page` always has latest `currentPage` value.

```
computed() {
    page() {
       return parseInt(this.currentPage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Computed property on v-model ? I need to add getters and setters also